# Will issuing a temporary queue per request vs per session affect performance?

Tags: java, performance, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

I've been looking at some server-side Java which uses JMS to interface with the ApolloMQ message broker.  Clients make synchronous requests with this server by doing the following:

1. Create a temporary queue used to receive the response
2. Send request to the standard request queue with 'reply-to' pointing to the new
   temporary queue
3. Wait for the response on the temporary queue
4. Delete the temporary queue and repeat

It seems like issuing a new temporary queue for each request may be expensive for the message broker, and likely introduces an additional round trip for each request in order to first create the temporary destination.  I don't want to spend a bunch of time verifying this myself and I was kinda hoping someone in the know could confirm this intuition.  Would it be better  to instead create a single temporary queue per client session and use the message/correlation id to match responses to requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it from the performance perspective: Is a message broker optimized for *sending/receiving messages* or to *create/remove queues*?

Likewise databases are not optimized to create and drop tables on the fly; it's insert/update/delete.

So I would go the "correlation ID" way.

*Update*

This does not necessarily mean to put the responses in the same queue as the requests. You could have one queue for each client/session.

Comment: Thanks for the word. Pretty much as I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

Using correlationIDs involves using selectors on message queues - this is slower than creating a temporary queue for the purposes of request response (see "Request-reply over JMS" at http://camel.apache.org/jms.html for a comparison of the various options).

Comment: So you say it's faster to create a queue for each *request/response cycle* than using one dedicated queue with selectors for each client/session?

Comment: I wonder this too.  If all clients were checking a shared queue for their responses then I'd worry more about selection overhead, but would this not be mitigated by each client having their own dedicated temp queue?

Comment: Yes, that's been my experience. From my understanding each selector on a queue has to be evaluated against every message in that queue sequentially. In that respect, they are different to selectors on a topic where the broker evaluates each selector before deciding which parties to distribute the messages to. If you sent 5 messages, that's up to 5 message selectors that need to be evaluated one by one. The performance gets worse as the number of selectors increases.

Comment: Could you provide a reference as to "reading a correlation ID implies using selectors"? Anyway, if you read every message from the client/session queue at once, and use the correlation ID has the hash key in a local cache, there is no need for sequential scanning on a queue. Please describe what could be faster.

Comment: Apologies, that's what I read between the lines - that's usually the way that it's done as it means consuming from a queue without pulling the messages off.